# MPAndroidChart how to display bar color with label bottom of chart in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library for bar chat display.
Chart display working fine.

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
```

But I want to display bottom of chart label with Bar color

```
 val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
entries.add(BarEntry(100f, 0))
entries.add(BarEntry(60f, 1))
entries.add(BarEntry(70f, 2))
entries.add(BarEntry(50f, 3))

val labels = ArrayList<String>()
labels.add("Total")
labels.add("Obtained")
labels.add("Highest")
labels.add("Average")
val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries,"Cells")

val data = BarData(labels, barDataSet)
barChart!!.data = data
barChart!!.setDescription("")
barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
```

Is there any solutions for that?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means **legend**. You can customize it this way

```
Legend l = chart.getLegend();
l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
l.setDrawInside(false);
l.setForm(LegendForm.SQUARE);
l.setFormSize(9f);
l.setTextSize(11f);
l.setXEntrySpace(4f);
```

and chart legend enabled:

```
chart.getLegend().setEnabled(true)
```

Comment: Thanks man, it's useful to display label position on chart, but display more then two label need to add multiple `BarDataSet`

Comment: You can use setCustom() method for legend